# Pass two value to a sub routine

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to pass a target.value and target.address to my sub routine, but for some reason i'm getting error "Expected: =".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
      sendToRoutine (Target.Address, Target.Value) <<== Error
   End If
End Sub


Sub sendToRoutine ( myTarget as String, myTargetValue as String)
   'Do Something with the values....
End Sub
```

Comment: Either put `Call` in front of the line or remove the `()` around the criteria.

Comment: geez, tells me how much i know vba lol

Comment: See [This is confusing. Why not just always use parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1179/procedure-calls/3818/this-is-confusing-why-not-just-always-use-parentheses#t=201701202011114768015) on Stack Overflow Documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `Call` in front of your function.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
      Call sendToRoutine(Target.Address, Target.Value) '<<== Not an error
   End If
End Sub


Sub sendToRoutine(myTarget As String, myTargetValue As String)
   'Do Something with the values....
End Sub
```